# Modelo Relacional Colegio

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Para una tarea debo hacer un modelo relacional para un Colegio (solo es un ejercicio de práctica). El objetivo es resolver problemas de organización.

Hice el modelo, identifiqué entidades y relaciones (aunque con algunas tengo dudas que expondré más abajo). Pero tengo aún así no sé si estaría correcto.

**Datos del Colegio:**

Colegio pequeño; Consta de 20 Cursos con 15 a 30 Alumnos por curso. (Un alumno solo le corresponde un curso claramente).

5 Asignaturas

10 Profesores (un profesor puede enseñar distintas asignaturas).

5 Salas (compartidas. Es decir, que cada cierto tiempo los cursos y profesores van cambiando de sala. No hay una sala exclusiva para un curso).

1 Jornada diurna.

**Modelo Relacional:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Dudas:**

1. Mi duda principal es que si la tabla `Clases` está correctamente implementada.
2. Tengo con la cardinalidad y relación entre las tablas `Profesor` y `Asignatura`.

   Tomando en cuenta que, un profesor puede enseñar distintas materias.
   (Hay 10 profesores y 5 materias).

   Lo que interpreté es que un profesor puede dictar varias materias y
   una materia puede ser dictada por varios profesores (más de un profesor.
   ¿Sería correcto? Y como es una relación Muchos a Muchos cree la tabla
   intermedia `Asignaturas_por_Profesor`
3. No sé si una entidad para agregar podría ser `Jornada`, ya que quizás en determinado momento dicho colegio puede optar por agregar más de una jornada. ¿O quizás también porque sea necesario en la tabla `Clases`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, para ser tu primer modelo, no se te da mal: muy bien la generalización de `Personas` :). Las cosas mejorables son bastante sutiles. Te las comento:

- `Notas_por_Alumno` no incluye al alumno, ¿cómo sabrías a qué alumno pertenece cada nota?
- La especificación te indica que un profesor puede dar más de una asignatura, pero no dice que una asignatura pueda ser impartida por más de un profesor. Lo que te premite propagar el `rut_profesor` a la tabla a`Asignaturas` y prescindir de la tabla `Asignaturas_por_Profesor`
- `Clases` no debería depender de `Asignaturas_por_Profesor`, sino directamente de `Asignaturas`, salvo que fuera impartida por más de un profesor y quisieras saber cuál de ellos está en el aula en cada momento. Pero no veo que algo así te lo estén pidiendo.
- `Asignaturas` debería depender del `Cursos`, de otra forma no tendrías forma de diferenciar las matemáticas de 1º de las de 2º, por ejemplo.

Como el modelado de datos no está muy bien visto en SO porque, al admitir diferentes soluciones, se considera basado en opiniones y es probable que cierren la pregunta, te animo que contactes conmigo a través del enlace a linkedin de mi perfil para aclarar tus dudas. Vía comentarios las explicaciones pueden ser larguísimas.

Espero que te haya resultado útil.